# Gulp.js and Variable File Names

Tags: css, gulp

I've got a directory called `css`. In it are CSS files that contian nothing but `@import` statements to other CSS chunks. I want to munge the `@import` statements into one file and add `.min.css` to the file name.

Before:

```
css
-- foo.css
-- bar.css
```

After:

```
css
-- foo.css
-- foo.min.css
-- bar.css
-- bar.min.css
```

I'm using [gulp-concat-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat-css) but it requires a string argument for the relative path of the generated file containing the concatenated css. What I want to do is pass in a variable with the filename of the current file being processed by `gulp.src('css/*.css')`

Here is my complete `gulp.js` file...

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var del = require('del');
var concatCSS = require('gulp-concat-css');
var cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');

gulp.task('clean:min-css', function () {
    // Delete all *.min.css files in the CSS directory so we don't get duplicates
    return del([
        'css/*.min.css'
    ]);
});

gulp.task('default', ['clean:min-css'], function() {
    gulp.src('css/*.css')
        // Munge contents of @import statements into one file
        .pipe( concatCSS( currentFileName + '.min.css' ) )

        // minify CSS
        .pipe( cssnano() )

        // Save out the new file
        .pipe( gulp.dest('css/') );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any simple solutions to this.

However, I don't think you need to use *gulp-concat-css*, looks like a combination of [*gulp-rename*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) and [*gulp-cssimport*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cssimport) will be enough:

```
var rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    cssimport = require('gulp-cssimport');
// ...
gulp.task('default', ['clean:min-css'], function() {
    return gulp.src('css/*.css')
           .pipe(cssimport({})) // process imports
           .pipe(cssnano()) // minify CSS
           .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' })) // change extension
           .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));
});
```

Actually, you'd consider using *gulp-sass*. It's capable of processing imports and compressing CSS files (`outputStyle: 'compressed'`).

Comment: The only problem is `gulp-concat-css` will rebase relative URLs like background-image:url(image.jpg); I was using `gulp-rename` and `gulp-cssimport` before.